# How to upload a photo to Tumblr using API v2 and OAuth using Actionscript/MXML?

Tags: actionscript-3, oauth, mxml, tumblr

Tumblr api: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting

I'm having the most trouble with how to use a bytearray to send the "url-encoded binary contents" - (from the tumblr api),  what to sign, and which headers to send.

I'm not using FileReference.upload because you can't use custom headers.

I'm going to go back through the versions of my code and find the one that worked the best so far and post it.

So here's my question:

How to upload a photo to Tumblr using API v2 and OAuth in Actionscript/MXML?

Also, It is an AIR app and I would prefer not having to upload it to a server and sending it to Tumblr from the server, Although I may end up doing this.

Edit:

Here is the only line I need to work out.

```
baseString.params = 'data[0]=' + URLEncoding.encode(byte.toString()).replace('~','%257E');
```

where byte is a bytearray for the file. If I take every other line of code I've written and replace that line with

```
            baseString.params = 'body=test';
```

I can post a text update to Tumblr.

Comment: having the exact same problem posting with javascript via jsOauth.  Did you ever get it working?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I ended up moving away from Actionscript towards JavaScript; where there were still massive pains with the Tumblr api. I ended up scrapping the Tumblr support for the project I was working on.